# HTML Audio player is not working in latest IOS web browser

Tags: ios, browser, html5-audio

I have implemented the HTML  tag in my webapp and attached the s3 aws mp3 url but its not working in iphone, working fine in android phone and windows browser.

I am uploading the audio by voice recording RTC angular, its working fine on android phones browser and windows browser, but its not playing the audio in iphone's browser, what should i do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.